# How to push only validation error messages into an array using Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel

I have a validator, it has error messages, and my goal is to get only error messages with the field names.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
   array(
      'firstField' => Input::get('firstFieldName');
      'secondField' => Input::get('secondFieldName');
   ),
   array(
      'firstField' => 'required';
      'secondField' => 'required';
   )
);

if($validator->fails()){
   return $validator->messages();
}
```

So, this piece of code is returning some values to my js file as following

```
function getErrorMessages(){
   //Some UI functions
   var myDiv = document.getElementById('messageDivID');
   $.post('validationRoute', function(returedValidatorMessageData)){
      for(var a in returedValidatorMessageData){
         myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.value + a;
      }
   }
}
```

Problem is, the only values i get from post request is like **firstField** **secondField** but i'd like to get like **firstField is required** message. What would be the easiest way ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a perfect approach i know, but created my own way as the answer :

```
if($validator->fails()){
       //get all the messages
       $errorArray = $validator->errors()->all(':message');
          //& operator means changes will affect $errorArray
          foreach($errorArray as &$a){
             $a = ucfirst($a);           //uppercases first letter (you can do this in laravel config too)
             $a = '<li>'.$a.'</li>';     //add to list
           }
       //add a string at the beginning of error message
       array_unshift($errorArray, '<p><b>The error messages are following :</b></p>');
       //implode and return the value
       return implode(' ',$errorArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's `messages()` method returns array with this format:

```
[
    "first_name" => [
        "First name is required."
    ]
]
```

Where keys are name of the field and values are arrays of error messages. So just modify your js using values instead of keys. Example:

```
for (var key in returedValidatorMessageData){
     console.log(returedValidatorMessageData[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should search in laravel official documentation... in the view use this

```
<!-- /resources/views/post/create.blade.php -->

<h1>Create Post</h1>

@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif

<!-- Create Post Form -->


 in controller :

public function name(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    // Store the blog post...
}
```

}